# How to order a LIST in F#

Tags: f#

Total F# n00b question.
How do I sort a LIST data structure?

Edit: Sorry, my data structure is actually a LIST.

maybe i should add my code since just using ".sort" hasn't worked:

```
let getDataFromDb (db: MyDB) Id =
Query.query <@ seq { 
    big honking database/FLinq query
    yield  (sec, pm, sr, trade, tradeRec, i, pm_firm, files, lt)
} @> |> List.ofSeq
```

when I change the last line of code to this:
            } @> |> List.ofSeq.sortBy fst
I get the following:

> Error  1   The field, constructor or member 'sortBy' is not defined

ugh, what a pain. I'm trying this now:

```
|> List.ofSeq |> List.sortBy
```

But I'm getting this:

> Error  1   Type mismatch. Expecting a     (Security * RoleContributor * RoleContributor * SuggestedTrade * SuggestedTradeRecommendation * Idea * RoleContributor * SupportingUploadedFile * LargeText) list -> 'a     but given a     ('b -> 'c) -> 'b list -> 'b list     The type '(Security * RoleContributor * RoleContributor * SuggestedTrade * SuggestedTradeRecommendation * Idea * RoleContributor * SupportingUploadedFile * LargeText) list' does not match the type ''a -> 'b'

Comment: this looks a bit like real, production code to me.  if it is, it's probably against your company's policy to put it on a site like SO.

Comment: yeah, i thought about masking it. maybe i should.

Comment: try |> List.ofSeq |> List.sortBy ..

Comment: Regarding your big honking query, it might be better to move it into a stored procedure. Or, if that's not an option, then you can reduce the degree of indentation by moving your joins into the same indent level like this: http://pastebin.com/shqsaPG9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Seq.sortBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353610.aspx) would do that.

However sorting implies you know the key values of the full sequence at the time of sorting, so by definition you cannot use this on infinite sequences.

Edit:
The equivalent for lists has the same name:
[List.sortBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353676.aspx)

MSDN example:

```
let sortedList2 = List.sortBy (fun elem -> abs elem) [1; 4; 8; -2; 5]
printfn "%A" sortedList2
```

Edit 2:

From your new example it seems like you have a list of tuples. Now it depends on what item in the tuple you want to search by.

Comment: this: let third (_, _, c) = c   from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx    was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

As others said, `Seq.sortBy` is the way to go. If you're using FLinq to read some data from a database, then it is a good idea to include the sorting as part of the database query (enclosed in `<@ .. @>`) so that the sorting is done on the SQL server:

```
let getDataFromDb (db: MyDB) Id = 
  <@ seq { big honking database/FLinq query 
             yield  (sec, pm, sr, trade, tradeRec, i, pm_firm, files, lt)
     |> Seq.sortBy (fun (_, _, _, _, _, i, _, _, _) -> i) @>
  |> List.ofSeq
```

To make this a little nicer, you could return tuple containing key and all other elements as nested tuple e.g `key, (sec, pm, ..., lt)` and then just sort using the first element:

```
 |> Seq.sortBy (fun (k, _) -> k)
```

(I had some troubles using tuples with LINQ to Entities, but I believe that it should work in LINQ to SQL).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Query.query <@ ... @>
|> List.sortBy (fun (sec, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) -> sec)
```

Note that using tuples with that many elements is really bad style in F#. Use something more structured like a record type to give names to the fields and avoid confusion.